# Angular 6 [ngValue] undefined

Tags: angular6

I am using Angular 6 and trying to create a form that consists of a dropdown menu with  tag using [ngValue] in it. Here is my code:

**View:**

```
 <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4">Title</label>
                        <select formControlName= "current_status" name="current_status">
                        <option [ngValue]="">Select any one</option>
                        <option [ngValue]="option-1">option-1</option>
                        <option [ngValue]="option-2">option-2</option>
                        <option [ngValue]="option-3">option-3</option>
                        <option [ngValue]="option-4">option-4</option>

                    </select>
                </div>
```

While I am trying to submit the form, the selected value is undefined.

**Error:**

> Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to
>   enable the production mode.
>
> {...,current_status: undefined}

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `value` instead

```
<select formControlName="current_status" name="current_status">
    <option [value]="">Select any one</option>
    <option [value]="option-1">option-1</option>
    <option [value]="option-2">option-2</option>
    <option [value]="option-3">option-3</option>
    <option [value]="option-4">option-4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use just 'value' options

```
<select formControlName="title">
            <option value="vk">Vkontakte</option>
            <option value="fb">Facebook</option>
            <option value="tw">Twitter</option>
            <option value="gp">Google</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

use it like this

```
            <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4">Title</label>
                    <select formControlName= "current_status" name="current_status">
                     <option value="">Select any one</option>
                     <option value="{{option.1.value}}">{{option.1.name}}</option>
                     <option value="{{option.2.value}}">{{option.2.name}}</option>
                     <option value="{{option.3.value}}">{{option.3.name}}</option>
                     <option value="{{option.4.value}}">{{option.4.name}}</option>

                </select>
            </div>
```

in your typescript file make an array called option's and in it have an value property and an name property

you could also make a forloop by making an array options

and then instead of option make it like this

```
<select formControlName= "current_status" name="current_status" *ngFor="let option of options">
<option value="{{option.value}}">{{option.name}}</option>
</select>
```

if the HTML is correct then this should make an option's form for how long you make your array and it is a bit better hope you like my answer and I help you.

note if you want the first one to be like select any one leave the value empty and the name select any one

Comment: i don't think this is correct and i got some stuff wrong but this would create an form with the value's but is not linked to the value's both ways but i don't know if you want that yes or no